# black screen after setContentView() during procedures

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
        checkForInternetConnection();
        exitWithOutInternet();
        gettingInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++){}
        findViewById(R.id.loading_login).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.login_btms).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Hi everyone, my problem is that after start of main_activity there are some procedures and in this time I would like to have a progressBar on my screen. After that a set its visibility to GONE a set menu VISIBLE, but during the procedures, there is only black screen.
There is the same problem if the code is without the setVisibility oders.

Thank you for your help

Comment: maybe because it stops on that big loop and doesn't go past it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your "procedures" are but it sounds like you want to use an `AsyncTask`. Also, your `for loop` there looks a little suspicious and probably unnecessary.

Implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do your "heavy lifting". You can set a `ProgressBar` in `onPreExecute()`, update it in `onProgressUpdate()` (if needed), and cancel it in `onPostExecute()`. You can also use any of these methods, except `doInBackground()`, to update your `UI`.

If you need more help then please explain what your methods do and why you have that huge `for loop` that appears to not do anything.

Comment: the fot loop is only for increase the time from setContentView to the end of onCreate()

Comment: did you read what codeMagic has written? You do not need to wait for the AsyncTask to complete. Simply include the last 2 methods in the body of the onPostExecute().

Comment: Yes put the code that changes the visibility of the `Views` in `onPostExecute()`. And I can only assume those other methods to network stuff which should go in or get called from `doInBackground()`. A loop like that is a terrible design on several levels. Android and Java have built in methods/objects to handle things like this. Use them

Answer (score 0):

One basic rule in Android -- and in all systems -- is **do the essential in the UI thread or main thread**

If you use your UI thread to make thinks like that horrible loop -- seriusly that code is very ugly, never can be a good solution for nothing -- or check the internet connection you lack the App.
Also if you do that in the onCreate method you will cause your app take a long time to start! The onCreatem method is only for the more essential code and app interface configuration.

There are a lot of methods to make hard work without lack the App. You can use threads, or for example use AsyncTask class that has a doInBackground method that always run in a separate thread and an onPostExecute method that always run on the UI Thread or Main Thread.
Also the recent Android API launchs a RunTimeError when you run internet connections on the UI Thread

Try this manual to understand the AsynTask class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the for loop. In fact, not only you do not need it, but it jams your main thread, which is BAD. My guess, is that you use an AsyncTask or another kind of thread and you need to set those 2 view's visibility after the task has completed.

This is not the way you should do it. It is not only pointless, but wrong on so many levels. Instead, include the last 2 methods:

```
 findViewById(R.id.loading_login).setVisibility(View.GONE);
 findViewById(R.id.login_btms).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In the onPostExecute() method of the AsyncTask. (if you are not using one, then use one).

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread or AsyncTask which is android style. It is not perfect, but could solve a lot of problems that could be panic by "new Thread", and easy to understand.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
    etContentView(R.layout.login_layout); 
    new LongTimeJob(this).execute();
}

static class LongTimeJob extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;
    public LongTimeJob(Activity _activity) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(_activity);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... _params) {
        checkForInternetConnection();
        exitWithOutInternet();
        gettingInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++){}
    }

    protected Void onPostExecute(Void _result) {
        if(mActivity.get()!=null) {
            mActivity.get()
                .findViewById(R.id.loading_login)
                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mActivity.get()
                .findViewById(R.id.login_btms)
                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } }
```